# FlatList does not display any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to learn React-native by writing a simple app, however I got stuck on getting FlatList to display dummy data.

I've checked some other answers here on SO but none of them seemed to solve my issue as everything's still blank.

App.tsx

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Platform, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

import FriendList from './src/FriendList';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
        <FriendList items={friends}></FriendList>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const friends = Array.apply(null, Array(60)).map((v, i) => {
  return {
    id: i,
    src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200?text=' + (i + 1)
  };
});
```

FriendList.tsx

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image, FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class FriendList extends Component<{items: Array<{id: number, src: string}>}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <FlatList data={this.props.items} renderItem={({item}) => (
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 1}}>
            <Image style={styles.imageThumbnail} source={{ uri: item.src}} />
          </View>
        )}
        numColumns={3}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30
  },
  imageThumbnail: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 100
  }
});
```

I should probably mention that the app builds fine with no errors / warnings, it just does not display any data inside FlatList.

Comment: Maybe you should add width and resizeMode to imageThumbnail as well.

Comment: Try use `console.log` for `this.props.items` to check if it's empty or not. Also add width to `imageThumbnail`

Comment: Setting width & resizeMode does nothing, console.log(this.props.items) returns an array of 60 items, as expected.

Comment: try to remove `Image` component and replace by a default text, and see if it's shows up

Comment: try removing `flex:1 ` from the `View` that is rendered inside `renderItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the MainContainer style from the FriendList component solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `flex: 1` from `renderItem`

```
<FlatList data={this.props.items} renderItem={({item}) => (
    // remove flex: 1 here
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', margin: 1}}>
        <Image style={styles.imageThumbnail} source={{ uri: item.src}} />
    </View>
  )}
  numColumns={3}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> please try this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    paymentDetails: [
      {
        id: 1,
        textData: 'data 1',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        textData: 'data 2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        textData: 'data 3',
      },
    ]
  }

  renderFlatListView = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={this.state.paymentDetails}
          extraData={this.state}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderFlatListDataView}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderFlatListDataView = ({ index, item }) => {
    console.log(item.id)
    return (
      <View key={index}>
        <Text>{item.textData}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderFlatListView()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: The issue was the MainContainer style

Answer (score 0):

**please use this code**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    const Details= [
      {
        id: 1,
        textData: 'test1',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        textData: 'test2',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        textData: 'test3',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        textData: 'test3',
      },
    ]

     class AppDetails extends Component {

      _renderItem= ({ index, item }) => {
        return (
          <View key={index}>
            <Text>{item.textData}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
             <FlatList
              data={Details}
              extraData={this.state}
              keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
             renderItem={this._renderItem}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        marginTop: 50,
      },
    });

    export default AppDetails;
```